# Is it redundant to say "percentage of one hundred"?

Tags: redundancy, percentages

I have seen the word "percentage" defined as "a number or rate that is expressed as a certain number of parts of something divided into 100 parts".  It seems to follow that 50% means "50 parts of something which is divided into 100 parts".  Does the word percentage implies that the whole is 100?  Am I being redundant if I use the phrase "percentage of one hundred"?

**Context**: I am trying to state explicitly that a number provided to my software should be in the form of "50" for 50%, not "0.50" (which, to be consistent, I would refer to as a percentage of one).  My usage is as follows:

> Provide the minimum discount given to this customer as a percentage of one hundred (15 for 15%).

Comment: percent comes from the Italian: per cento. x number for every one hundred, right. In your context, I would say: as a percentage. Percentage is by definition "of one hundred". So percentage of one hundred is redundant.

Comment: "Percentage of one hundred" is redundant; there is no other kind of percentage. "percentage of one" is meaningless. In the context of your program, I can tell you from experience that you need to carefully validate your input here, and also provide clear instruction - as per YLearn's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!  Percent (Per Cent) literally means "of one hundred."

Answer (score 1):

It is redundant, but I think what you meant to say is: "Provide the minimum discount given to this customer **in the form of a percentage** (**and not as a decimal**)".

If you don't want people to use the % symbol, give them an example of how to state it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is redundant ... for percent (%), "parts of 100" is assumed.  Where 50% would designate half (of 100), 0.50% would designate one half of one percent ... as would 0.5%.